# Unable to initiate iOS app purchase. Authentication issue

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, authentication

I am developing an app for iOS which includes in-app purchases. The app is already in App Store, and I am working on an update.

When I tap on a locked item, I am prompted to enter password of my Apple ID. If I enter wrong password, it says

> The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was
>   incorrect. Please try again”, even though the ID / password are (we
>   believe) correct.

But when I enter a correct password, it says

> Your apple ID or password is incorrect

Authentication fails in both cases, but notice the error message is worded differently, which means it recognises that the password is correct, but sends a failed authentication message.

The current version of my app does not have this issue, authentication succeeds when correct password is added, but the update that I am working on has this problem.

Additional info:
The app is a cordova (cross-platform) app. The plugin I am using is https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase

Doubts:
Could it be because the update of the app is still a development ipa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, test only on the device. In-app purchase testing doesn't work in the Simulator.

Second, there are two Apple ID / password pairs in play here. There's *yours*, on the device you are testing on, and there's the *sandbox account* that you created when you created the in-app purchase. You need to test with the sandbox account. So you have to sign out of your own iCloud account and into the sandbox account before you can test.

Comment: oh! let me try with my sandbox account. I will let you know

Comment: Extremely delighted to tell you, you were right. No authentication issues when I use the sand box tester account. Thanks a million!

Comment: You are very welcome. I need hardly tell you that I knew the answer to this question because I've made this mistake myself. :)